# Get the html of a drupal article via jQuery $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I'm storing an article I've written in drupal 7. Is there a way to retrieve the content of that article (the html content) using jQuery's `$.get()` from another web application ? (Not the whole drupal page, just the article content)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this module helps you: https://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it using the Services API and Content API together